# How can I add an assembly binding redirect to a .net core unit test project?

Tags: .net-core, xunit.net

I'm trying to create a .net core unit test project against framework 4.6.1 which tests an project dependent on Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (10.0.0.0). Prior to .net core I'd add an app.config file with the binding redirect.  I've tried this but the binding redirect does not seem to be picked up when I run from visual studio. What can I do to fix the binding redirect?

Comment: Binding redirects are gone: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/407. I think they still worked at some point, during release candidates, if you specified them on an _App.config_ (yes, even if it's a web app). But my guess is that not even that _hack_ is working anymore.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you reference Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk >= 15.3.0 in your project it automatically turns on the required MSBuild properties, as Fabian says below. See [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5335#issuecomment-306318810.).

---

You can add the following settings to your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Otherwise adding them to an `app.config` in the root of the solution, as Joao says, works too. Make sure you set its `Copy to Output Directory` setting to `Copy always` or `Copy if Newer`.

Comment: This answer also works for project files (*.csproj) that were created with VS 2017 version 15.2 or 15.3 and which are for the full .NET Framework, e.g. .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: app.config in a unit test project referencing .net core 2.0 currently breaks the test host

Answer (score 10):

Referencing the NuGet package `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` >= 15.3.0 (I used `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 15.3.0-preview-20170601-03`) solved this problem for me. That package automatically turns on the MSBuild properties mentioned in @Mardoxx's answer.

(I got this info from [Martin Andreas Ullrich](https://github.com/dasMulli) at https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5335#issuecomment-306318810.)

Comment: Brilliant, did not know this. Thank you.

Comment: @D.R this does not work for me on a project that doesn't have an Exe output type - had to specify explicitly as with the accepted answer

Comment: I can confirm it works for DLL projects as well. All our test projects are library projects.

Answer (score 1):

In my case none of the solutions mentioned above helped (even if the binding redirects are generated automatically or added manually, looks like these hacks are really not working anymore as @Joao suggested).

So I added the desired version of the package to my project, even if it is not used directly and this resolved the issue. I don't like this approach, but this was the only way working for me.

Hopefully this method can help others as well.