# How can I use a .NET Framework class in a .NET Standard project (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController)

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, servicecontroller

I am looking to use the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` class in a .NET Standard 2.0 project. In order to do so I downloaded the Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility packet from NuGet, whic includes among other things  ( I also tried to simply download the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController packet by itself). I can now use the ServiceController without any problem within my class, but when I try to run the program I get:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I guess I'm missing something crucial here, especially since as far as I can tell the version I installed is 4.5.0 and the version it is looking for is the 4.2.1.0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: install this NuGet package in the project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/ and edit runtime bindings in app.config

Comment: That is the project I had initially installed (I guess the Compatibility package is simply a collection of individual packages). For the bindings, since I am using .NET Standard I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111749/adding-a-bindingredirect-to-a-net-standard-library
that the way to go was to add <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects> to true in the .csproj file, but it still gives me the same error. Should I create an app.config to the project as well? How should I add the binding?

Comment: add a app.config and [add this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element) for System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController to redirect 4.2.1.0 to 4.5

Comment: @magicandre1981 There shouldn't need to be an app.config in a .NET Standard library. The entire point is it's a library, not an application.

Comment: Ok so it took me a while because I had to work on another project... the answer was rather simple in the end, the .NET Standart project was actually referenced from a .Net Framework project. The .Net Framework had the v4.2.1 automatically loaded while the .NET Standard had the v4.5 due to the compatibility package. So i installed the compatibility package on the .Net Framework and it all worked out