# Find out User Role in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

My ASP.NET Core application uses VB.net library that needs to know privileges of the current user. It used `My.User.IsInRole(ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrator)` call before, but in asp.net core it comes up with the following exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.User' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'

I also tried to use `System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrators")`

But this one will not load `system.web`

Is there an alternative way to do it?

Comment: I think you will want to explore the [Authorize] attribute on one of your Controllers.  See other SO question with that topic.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns this is happening not within the controller. But within the library controller calls

Comment: You might have a problem until [.NET Core 3 is released](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2018/11/12/visual-basic-in-net-core-3-0/), You can try [binding redirects for .net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46120907/3419825)