# ASP.Net Core dll binding redirect not working

Tags: asp.net-core, assembly-binding-redirect

I have a ASP.Net Core project which references a .Net Framework library (our own lib). This library references two 3rd party libraries. The two 3rd party libs reference RestSharp but different versions. The 3rd party lib that references that old RestSharp version fails with the error

> Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

In a .Net framework app, I would have created a binding redirect in the config file which would have worked, but I dont know how to get the same result in .Net Core app.
I tried adding the following binding redirect in the app.config file of the .Net Core app but that did not work. I also added a app.config file in our library with the redirect but that did not work as well.

```
      <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" publicKeyToken="null" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-105.0.1.0" newVersion="106.3.1.3" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Has anybody got a solution for this issue?

Comment: Did you make sure that restsharp is installed as a nuget dependency? Bindingredirects do not exist anymore for .NET Core and .NET Standard.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111749/adding-a-bindingredirect-to-a-net-standard-library

Comment: Yes the RestSharp package was installed via nuget. I can see that the application.exe.config file has the auto generated redirects in the .Net Core app. I have also tried the suggested approach in your provided link but did not work. If binding redirect is not supported, how else can this problem be solved.

Comment: At least on some early versions of ASP.Net Core, you could add the .net framework style redirect bindings with an app.config file: https://blog.rytmis.net/2016/03/29/asp-net-core-and-assembly-binding-redirects/