# Common practice to load the dependency(different version of dll) in program

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, dependencies, .net-standard

Suppose there is a code which use 2 third party dll's. one is `NLog.Extensions.Logging` version `1.6.1` for logging other is lets say `CryptoProvider.dll` written in .net standard 2.0. `NLog.Extensions.Logging` internally using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` version `2.1.0` while `CryptoProvider.dll` internally use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` version `2.0.0`. So now there is a issue regarding version mismatch. So how should I design to CryptoProvider dll. so that resolve the issue .

Answer (score -2):

there is a possibility to redirect assembly binding using the `app.config` file [assemblyBinding\bindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) like below

```xml
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

This can redirect all assembly Newtonsoft.Json version references to be resolved to `12.0.0.0`.
Usually VS adds those redirects automatically if installed packages has different dependency versions.

But it works only if there are no breaking changes between the redirected version.

Not sure that it will work to mix between .net framewok and .net core assemblies.

[Assembly binding redirect for .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111749/adding-a-bindingredirect-to-a-net-standard-library) can be done using `deps.json`

Comment: bindingRedirect is only work for .net framework. If I am not wrong.

Comment: @vikky added link for .net core assembly binding redirection