# Dependencies of packages conflicts with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, dependencies, package, nuget, azure-functions

I've an Azure Function project *(.NET Framework)* and I've this NuGet packages installed.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Swagger" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.5.0" />
```

The project has also an other reference to an other created project. There I've next dependancies:

```xml
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" version="3.0.5" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.WebKey" version="3.0.5" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.3" targetFramework="net472" />
```

When I run a function, I got this Error:

> Could not load file or assembly `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed` or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What's wrong with the packages? I've been searching a day for a solution but the only thing I find is that the dependencies of each packages uses an different version of `Newtonsoft.Json`. The 
Newtonsoft dependency of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` must be 9.0.1, while others stand on 10.0.3 or higher.

How could I solve this?

Comment: Make sure that you reference the same version of the assembly across all projects or use [binding redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111749/adding-a-bindingredirect-to-a-net-standard-library).

Comment: Use Azure Function V3 should solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newtonsoft json version is = not >=. This problem has been around for a long time, MS tracking this work here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/304

Create function v3 to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-version), the version specified is the lowest version required. You can learn more about package versioning [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges).