# Assembly binding redirect in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, assemblies

How do I do assembly binding redirect in .NET Core?

I found this question asked a few time with no solutions offered. The situation is trivial. I have a package refering to assembly A in version 10. I want to use assembly A in version 12. In a standard .NET it works perfectly with this:

```html
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-15.1.52.23" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: You need to check this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/46120907/11398810.

Answer (score 9):

With help of Rena, adding

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

to the project file helped. The .config file got autogenerated with the correct binding redirect.

Comment: This doesn't work for .NET 6.0.