# Using different versions of the same assembly with .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In full .net framework, we could use two versions of a same assembly thanks to binding redirection :

like that :

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" />
                <codeBase version="1.1.0.0" href="v2.1\Castle.Core.dll" />
                <codeBase version="1.2.0.0" href="v2.2\Castle.Core.dll" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

source : [Using different versions of the same assembly in the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460542/using-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-the-same-folder)

How to do in that with .net core ?

Comment: Here is as great article: [Nick Craver, Binding Redirects](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that´s not possible at the moment:

[Adding a bindingRedirect to a .Net Standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111749/adding-a-bindingredirect-to-a-net-standard-library)

Maybe the link will give you some more insights. There it is about .NET Standard as well as .NET Core.

Comment: Do you know if it will be available in the future ?

Comment: @k4st0r42 Sorry, I don't have any info on that. But some concepts from the .NET framework will probably never be migrated to .NET Core or .NET 5, others will be migrated later. You could ask this question to the .NET Core´s team on GitHub. Maybe they can told you more information an that topic.