# Why there is no Binding redirection concept in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection

Context:

I have been working lately on a tool that perform analysis on a given binary(resulting assembly from compilation process). the objective of the analysis is to alert developer about missing dependencies that will be used at runtime.

Using reflection, I am able to get the needed dependencies, for .NET Framework i am also reading `.config` files to get binding redirection and take them into account.

My questions are:

Is there any support for binding redirection or similar concept in .NET Core ? If yes is there any alternative to that ?
I know that there is `.deps` file but i think it's not meant to be manually modified?

N.B. I have tried to modify `.deps` file manually to redirect Newtonsoft.Json to a specific version and it always fails to found the dependency, i found that somehow strange because CoreCLR
parses the `.deps` file to get the dependencies as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/default-probing).

I have seen this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111749/adding-a-bindingredirect-to-a-net-standard-library/46120907#46120907) but without no specific answer for .NET Core

Comment: In my opinion it's pretty inconvenient that they've decided to drop support for things like the ```probingPath``` in .NET core, this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10366) on github is related to that. But it seems like the ```.deps.json``` file is the way to go, as explained [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/host-probing.md)

Comment: https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/

Comment: @OlivierRogier `.NET Core’s simplified assembly loading means it just works` what that's mean? that what i am searching for.

Comment: @youssefjirari I don't know, sorry, I'm using only the Framework up to 4.7.

Comment: So far, it really looks to me as if it "just works" (unless doing very weird things). @youssefjirari Can you give a specific example when you get a problem?