# Use newer version of library in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core application that uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore version 2.2.0` library. This library uses `System.Text.Encoding.Web version 4.5.0` library internally. We need to upgrade the application to use at least `System.Text.Encoding.Web version 4.5.1` library due to security issues.

How can this be done in a .NET Core application?

We could do this easily in a .NET application, by using `AssemblyRedirect` properties in the `web.config` file.

Comment: Binding redirects are a .NET framework concept, there are no binding redirects on .NET Standard and .NET Core.A detailed explanation is given [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111749/adding-a-bindingredirect-to-a-net-standard-library?answertab=votes#tab-top), you can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no binding redirects in .NET Core. Dynamic linking are resolved at runtime and is controlled by the `.deps.json` manifest file which is usually generated by the compiler during compilation.

One way to achieve what you want is to simply reference `System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.5.1` directly in your source project. This will override any transitive reference to `System.Text.Encodings.Web` via the ASP.NET Core framework:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web" Version="4.5.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  ...other dependencies
</ItemGroup>
```

Rebuild the code and the compiler will now generate the correct `.deps.json` file so that your program will load the new version of `System.Text.Encodings.Web` at runtime.

Comment: Thank you @scharnyw, I learnt something new today.