# reference to type 'icommandexecutor' claims it is defined in 'webdriver' when using IOSDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

Updating my Selenium project to Selenium 4 results with the following error:
`reference to type 'icommandexecutor' claims it is defined in 'webdriver'`.
The error is actually pointing to the following line:
`m_driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new Uri(""), caps);`
This line works as expected with Selenium v3.141.

I have the following dependencies installed:

`Selenium Support - v4.0`,
`Selenium Webdriver - v4.0`,
`DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers  - V3.11.0`,
`Appium.Webdriver - v4.0`

I have tried downgrade `Selenium Support` to `3.141` but still getting the same error.

Comment: probably related / similar but the exact package versions you need might vary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927803/reference-to-type-error-when-adding-the-dotnetseleniumextras-package-extension

Comment: @rene the post mainly talks about v3.x. I didn't manage doing the same for v4.x