# C# .NET Core : two projects referencing one project with different versions, if executed one project from another, exception is thrown. How to fix?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, nuget, packagereference

I have 2 C# projects 'B' and 'C', both are console apps, and one class library 'A' also.

'C' points to latest 'A' i.e. 1.2.2 and when a code from 'B' (which points to older 'A' i.e. 0.0.1) is executed via 'C', an exception is thrown, as since there was some file present in the older 'A' which is not in the latest 'A'.

Here is the exception:

> Could not load type 'A.xyz' from assembly 'A.Utils, Version=1.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

[image: FlowChart Describing Dependencies]

How to make 'B' project use its own version of dependency instead of what version its user 'C' has?

Or, in other words: how to call a method of 'B' from 'C' using 0.0.1 'A' instead of 1.2.2 'A'?

- I have tried out experimenting with "PrivateAssets" in the `.csproj` but that didn't help.
- I cannot use the "Aliases" as 'A' is a source generator lib, so the error comes from a generated file, whose namespace I cannot edit.
- I have already tried running it in a new thread, but got the same error.

Comment: u can use binding redirects in both project - for project  B it should redirect to older version and for project C newer version ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365736/assembly-binding-redirect-how-and-why

Comment: I am working with .NET Core, and as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/46120907/14465779, nuget's `PackageReference` should be handling that automatically