# Why is Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk not added by default to an MSTest project using .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mstest

I am writing a small application using TDD as a way to try and learn TDD. I created a new solution with a class library that will hold the functionality of my application. Then I added a new MSTest project to the solution. Everything is targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 since that is what I build off of at work.

I added [Docker.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet) and started writing some tests to play around with it and learn how to use it. I started getting binding errors and it took me longer than I'd like to admit to figure out how to fix it. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42806831/8657981) post that had me edit the tests.csproj file to enable binding redirects. That fixed the issue, but I was annoyed by the thought of manually adding this to all test projects. The first line of their answer mentioned `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` which seemed odd, since that wasn't in my project. Looking around I found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/2092) github issue where people are saying that this is a required dependency to run unit tests. I can say I definitely was able to build my project and run tests that both passed and failed. So I removed my edits to tests.csproj and added the most recent release of the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` nuget package. I was able to run tests again without binding redirect issues.

Why am I able to test without this and why is this package not included when I create a new test project?

Answer (score 0):

That `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` package is not needed by legacy .NET Framework projects (which are not migrated to the new SDK style).

All links you pasted above are for the new SDK style projects (for .NET Core primarily).

Comment: Do you know the "correct" way to solve my problem? As it stands, adding an MSTest project to my .NET Framework solution does not allow for binding redirects by default. Is this working as intended?

Comment: @OsakaRhymes you will have to post a new question with more information on what is exactly the original problem. You shouldn't expect anyone to be able to help on the words of "I started getting binding errors".